# How to load data in textbox from ajax using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I tried to load simple ajax return value in textbox using bootstrap typeahead function. If I check it by alert it return data but When I type in textbox there is nothing. I tried with direct data to `source:['albama','utah']` without ajax it works fine.  I have included all related files. I

```
<input type ="text" id ="subjects" data-provide="typeahead" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#subjects').typeahead

                ({
                        source: $.ajax({


                                          url: "./test/test.php",
                                           type: "POST",
                                          data: "search=" + $('#subjects').attr('value'),
                                        success: function(data)
                                        {

                                var subjects = ['Albamsa', 'Washington', 'New York', 'Arlington', 'New Jersey'];                                          return subjects;

                                        }
                                })



                });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$('#subjects').typeahead({

    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.getJSON(
            './test/test.php',
            { query: query },
            function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
    }

});
```

Also use `json_encode` function in your script for returned values