# Typeahead with database as source

Tags: yii, bootstrap-typeahead

This snippet works and it correctly sets data from Table Product and column name as input for bootstrap typeahead extension for YII.

but, I have ended up writing a SELECT ALL from Table Product which is having large number of data.

Can we modify this so that a WHERE condition can be added to the DataProvider on user input event. Based on each alphabet entered, a new query could then be fired and only a subset of data retrieved?

```
            <?php 
            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Product');

            $dataArray = $dataProvider->getData();
            $myarray = array();

            foreach ($dataArray as $data){
                array_push($myarray, CHtml::encode($data->name));
            }               


            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTypeahead', array(
                'name'     => 'typeahead',
                'options'=>array(
                    'name'=>'typeahead',
                    'source'=>$myarray,
                    'items'=>4,
                    'matcher'=>"js:function(item) {
                        return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase());
                    }",
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'search-query span3', 'placeholder'=>"Search" ), 
            )); ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load data in textbox from ajax using twitter bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874743/how-to-load-data-in-textbox-from-ajax-using-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Use Ajax to load the value on-the-fly. By the way, you don't need to specify the `matcher` if it's unchanged from the default like you have it above.

Comment: @pickypg, What would be better to get all data initially from database as source or using Ajax to run the query multiple times for each alphabet entered ?

Comment: That's up to you really. "A lot" of data is quite subjective. You can adjust the behavior of the Ajax request to limit the number of times that you hit the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you start to supply a function to `source`, then you have the power to manipulate what happens, including how often you send requests.

```
minLength: 3, // <- custom option
source: function(query, process) {
    var longEnough = query.length >= this.options.minLength;
    // you can create custom variables (this.search) that a remembered across
    //  searches
    if (longEnough && (! this.search || whateverRuleYouWantToLimitBy)) {
        // remember the query so that you can compare it to the next one
        this.search = query;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajaxsearch.php?value=' + query,
            type: "GET",
            success: process
        });
    }
}
```

I have some code that does something similar, and I cache the results returned by the Ajax code, and then I see if the new `query` string has the potential to change the results (e.g., if you limit by 4 results, but I only have 3 results, then a `query` that simply adds to the last `query` (search) has no need to hit the server).

Alternatively, you can kick off a timer that effectively waits for the user to stop typing to avoid the behavior of hitting the server for every key press. Technically, that results in slower feedback, but it's better for the server and mobile users.  This is appropriate on sites that have a lot of traffic.